# Can a page loaded in an iframe find out the url of its parent?

Tags: javascript, iframe, browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [get parent.location.url - iframe - from child to parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413414/get-parent-location-url-iframe-from-child-to-parent)

Is it possible for a page that's been loaded inside of another page in an  tag to find out more about its parent than just the fact one exists?

I know that JS can check if the current page is the top window. If it isn't, chances are it's being loaded in an iframe. But can it find out more? For instance, can it execute some code to find the URL of the top frame?

Comment: what have you tried?  You seem to know you have access to `parent` and `top` so maybe the answer is visible from there.

Comment: You could use [`document.referrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.referrer)

Comment: `window.opener` perhaps?

Comment: @Malk it is not a pop up!

Comment: Is the iframe in the same domain as the parent?

Comment: @Malk: That doesn't seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/gSH3B/

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle! It looks like `window.top.location.href` is alerting the desired text: http://jsfiddle.net/gSH3B/2/