# Issue accessing parent URL from child window

Tags: javascript

Suppose parent window has abc.xyz.com url and, I am opening a child window using: window.top.open

I am getting parent window object in child window using window.opener and polling the parent window url using window.opener.location.href.

Now, if the user click on a link in the parent window, which navigates to def.xyz.com then the window.opener.location.href is giving 'Permission Denied' and window.opener.closed is returning true. (in child script)

**I need to change my child window if the parent window is not inside xyz.com**

How do I know that the parent is navigated to xyz.com or some other domain?

Answer (score 0):

You can add some javascript to the **parent** window that modifies the child when it's URL changes. Using the `window.onunload` event would do the job:

```
window.onunload=function(){
    childWindow.location.href = 'parentURLChanged.html';
};
```

Instead of changing the location completely you could also only add a `hash` to the URL so It would change from **child.html** to **child.html#parentHasChanged**.
If you want more complete communication between these two windows I suggest you use the [jQuery postMessage Plugin](http://postmessage.freebaseapps.com/). It allows you to send and receive messages between two Windows or Frames and also works *cross-domain*.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
query = window.parent.location.search.substring(1)
```

referenced from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413414/get-parent-location-url-iframe-from-child-to-parent). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625733/how-do-i-get-around-window-opener-cross-domain-security) one can also help.