# iframe DOM overwrite

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm toggling some navigation animation to display and hide particular `li` elements. I'd like to keep my elements displayed every time the user is on the main screen. I've successfully maintained the `nav` items displayed on initial load.

Here is a demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/lorenabrito/p9jm59db/22/

If the content is not being interacted with it will redirect to the main page through a `.replace()`

However, if the `nav` is hidden and the inactivity condition is triggered, the navigation stays closed on redirect, causing `nav` duplication.  I know the `nav` duplicates because the main screen page is loading inside the iframe in the main screen.

Ideally, I'd like to overwrite the DOM with the main screen content when the page inactivity redirect is triggered. I momentarily thought perhaps I could set a condition to return when any new content has been loaded in the iframe, but with the replace I'm using the `src` value doesn’t change. I don't know if I've looked at this too long or if just not possible.

All three pages are using the same domain.

I'm currently console logging every time the iframe loads.

I've found [Access child iFrame DOM from parent page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181911/access-child-iframe-dom-from-parent-page) the most helpful.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

```
//main page with navigation 
<iframe id="main" src="http://main-screen.html"></iframe>

//second page 
//http://second-screen.html
if (inactivity > 3) // waits 3 mins. 
  window.location.href = 'http://main-screen.html'; 
}

//third page 
//http://third-screen.html
if (inactivity > 3) // waits 3 mins. 
  window.location.href = 'http://main-screen.html'; 
}
```

My apologies for not posting a demo right away. Thank you!

Comment: Could you create the similar demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: issue is a bit hard to fully understand without a demo, not sure if it will help but can take a look at postMessage API ... helpful for communicating between windows

Comment: Sure, [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/lorenabrito/p9jm59db/22/)

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for the great reference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was already successfully writing the DOM structure of the window with with the nested iframe. Ultimately, I came to the conclusion during the development of the project that my initial approach was messy. I was seeking to replace that windows DOM with the most recently loaded iframe.

In the end I learned a great deal about iframes!

- [get parent.location.url - iframe - from child to parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413414/get-parent-location-url-iframe-from-child-to-parent)
- [Access child iFrame DOM from parent page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181911/access-child-iframe-dom-from-parent-page)
- [Is there a way to uniquely identify an iframe that the content script runs in for my Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26010355/is-there-a-way-to-uniquely-identify-an-iframe-that-the-content-script-runs-in-fo/26014716#26014716)